# Swift File Manager Class

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am working on a project that gathers real-time location data and I have to store that data in a file. Currently, I am working on a class that can make a file and stores the data. It works when I call the write function once, but when I call it again it writes over the previous line instead of going to the next. I was wondering how I could modify my code so it would write at the next line.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


class dataManager {
    @Published var dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    lazy var fileURL = dir!.appendingPathComponent("coordinates.txt")
    
    func write(text: String) {
        print(dir!.path)
        do {
            try text.write(to: self.fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
        }
        catch {/* error handling here */}
    }
}

var manage = dataManager()
manage.write(text: "hello")
manage.write(text: "hi")
```

Comment: There is no simple `String` function to append to a file.  You can use `String(contentsOf:)` to get the current contents of your file, append the new value to that string and the write it back to the file or you can use a `FileHandle` so that you can append to the file, but probably Core Data is a better solution

Comment: @Paulw11 the issue with that (as I’m sure you’re aware, but I’ll mention it explicitly for OP) is that 1. As the file gets bigger and bigger, the `String(contentsOf:)` call will take longer and longer. Because it’s a blocking call, I recommend *completely* avoiding that API, unless you’re writing a one-off script. 2. Append-only writes are a pattern that operating systems provide (and are preferable because they don’t require any reading of the file, nor unnecessary overwriting of the whole file), but String and FileManager don’t have any convenient wrapper APIs for it.

Comment: Looks like [`FileManager.write(contentsOf:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle/3516320-write) is the API your looking for (after first using [`seekToEnd()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle/3516319-seektoend))

Comment: @Alexander I looked at the documentation of both links you sent and to be honest I am confused. I learned swift about a week or two ago and still am not very proficient in it. I would really appreciate it if you could send the changes of the code that I have to make.

Comment: Can you narrow is down a bit? What are you confused about in particular? This doesn’t really much have to do with Swift in particular, it’s based off the same Unix file model that you might have used in any other language. Are you new to programming in general, or swift specifically?

Comment: @NishchayJaiswal, have you found the solution?

Comment: @Indrajeet I decided to scrap the idea of storing data locally and have shifted to using google firebase to store the data. If you have any experience in swift I would really appreciate it if you could answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73095252/onappear-function-not-working-with-navigationlink. Thanks