# .onAppear() function not working with NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am working on a project that gathers real-time location data and stores it in a database (using google firebase). I am relatively new to Swift but have been coding for about 2 years. I have created a basic HomePage UI and a MapView UI, using a navigation link to move from page to page. The MapViewModel class is a class used to gather location data from the user. I am trying to call a method of the MapViewModel class with .onAppear. Although when I run the program the function is not called and "inside" isn't printed on the terminal. Am I missing something on how .onAppear and navigation links work? Please let me know what the best solution would be to call the function when the view is switched to MapView.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct HomePage: View {
    @State private var viewModel = MapViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                LinearGradient(
                    gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, Color(red:0.18, green: 0.79, blue: 0.91, opacity: 1.0)]),
                    startPoint: .topLeading,
                    endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                NavigationLink {
                    MapView()
                }
                label: {
                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .trim(from: 0.5)
                            .frame(width: 450, height: 450)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.89, blue: 0.36, opacity: 1.0))
                        
                        Text("Navigate")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(size:32, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                            .padding(.bottom, 280)
                    }
                    .position(x: 195, y: 900)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MapView: View {
    @State private var viewModel = MapViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region, showsUserLocation: true)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .accentColor(Color(.systemPink))
            .onAppear {
                print("inside")
                viewModel.checkIfLocationServiceIsEnabled()
            }
    }
}

final class MapViewModel : NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 33, longitude: -120), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
     
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    
    func checkIfLocationServiceIsEnabled() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager!.delegate = self
        }
        else {
            print("Print error message")
        }
    }
    
    func checkLocationAuthorization() {
        guard let locationManager = locationManager else { return }
        switch locationManager.authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            print("Location restricted")
        case .denied:
            print("You have denied location permission, go to settings")
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("Inside")
            if locationManager.location?.coordinate != nil {
                region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationManager.location!.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
            }
            else {
                print("Location not found")
            }
            
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        checkLocationAuthorization()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,  didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let lastLocation = locations.last!
        print(lastLocation)
                   
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomePage()
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't use `@State` with  a view model class. Change it to `@ObservedObject` in the `MapView` and `HomePage`. Also, what even is `Map` in your MapView? I can't find any information relates to it??

Comment: @tail I believe Map comes from MapKit. I have linked to documentation that I used for MapKit --> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/map. Also, could you explain the difference between '@State' and '@ObservedObject'?

Comment: `@State` is mostly for an internal variable of a struct. When you want to communicate between a view model and a struct, you need to use `@Published` for the class and `@ObservedObject` for the struct, otherwise your data and view won't be updated properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@StateObject var viewModel = MapViewModel()` in your `HomePage` view. Add `.environmentObject(viewModel)` to your `NavigationView` and the corresponding `@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MapViewModel` in `MapView`. Works for me.

This is the code I used for my tests, that works for me.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HomePage()
    }
}

struct HomePage: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = MapViewModel() // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                LinearGradient(
                    gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, Color(red:0.18, green: 0.79, blue: 0.91, opacity: 1.0)]),
                    startPoint: .topLeading,
                    endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                NavigationLink {
                    MapView()
                }
                label: {
                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .trim(from: 0.5)
                            .frame(width: 450, height: 450)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.89, blue: 0.36, opacity: 1.0))
                        
                        Text("Navigate")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(size:32, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                            .padding(.bottom, 280)
                    }
                    .position(x: 195, y: 900)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                }
            }
        }.environmentObject(viewModel) // <-- here
    }
}

struct MapView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MapViewModel // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
            Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region, showsUserLocation: true)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .accentColor(Color(.systemPink))
        .onAppear {
            print("\n----> in onAppear \n")
            viewModel.checkIfLocationServiceIsEnabled()
        }
    }
}

final class MapViewModel : NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 33, longitude: -120), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
    
    func checkIfLocationServiceIsEnabled() {
        print("\n----> in checkIfLocationServiceIsEnabled")
    }
}
```

If that does not work with your system, try this:

```
struct MapView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MapViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {  // <-- here
            Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region, showsUserLocation: true)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .accentColor(Color(.systemPink))
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("\n----> in onAppear \n")
            viewModel.checkIfLocationServiceIsEnabled()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I used the code adjustments that you sent me and it works perfectly!